# how to use linprog/ other matlab function to solve f'x-b = 0 with x is all positive?

Tags: matlab

I just want to know how to set this up. Seems like I can min f'x with linprog but not when f'x - b.

```
f' =  [0.2000    0.0100    0.0100         0    0.0200    0.0100;
    1.5700    1.3600    0.1000    0.0500    0.1600    0.1000;
    0.2500    2.2800    4.2200    2.5100    0.6000    0.3600;
         0         0    1.1000    4.8600    6.3900    1.2800;
         0         0         0         0    2.1400    6.3200;
         0         0         0         0         0    7.6600]
b = [ 0.0230;
    0.1106;
    0.5086;
    2.1678;
    4.3263;
    7.7430]
```

I want to solve for x to minimize f'x-b where x is all positive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, apart from the fact that the `f'` assignment will throw an error in MATLAB, `f'x-b=0` is the same as `f'x=b`. So you can solve it by typing `f'\b`.